# want current execution logs in karate.log file instead of all previous execution

Tags: karate

Require only current execution logs in karate.log file. Actually all previous execution and current execution logs are getting logged in karate.log file under target folder. Is there any way to log only current execution logs in karate.log file? Please give suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you launch your tests? If you're using maven, `mvn clean install` instead of `mvn install` will clean /target before the test.

Comment: thanks @adrien. it is working as expected while running with 'clean install'